# Вычислить 1*2 + 2*3*4 + 3*4*5*6 +

Tags: c++, циклы

Мне нужно вычислить 1*2 + 2*3*4 + 3*4*5*6 + ...
в моей программе при вводе 2 выдаёт 32,а должно 26

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "rus");
    int n;
    int p = 1;
    cout << "Введи число: ";
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0, s = 0, d = 0,j = 0; i < 2 * n; i++, j = i + 1 , p = p * j, s = s + p) {
            cout << "Результат: " << s << endl;
        }


    }
```

Comment: Программа не соответствует формуле, чего гадать-то... Hint: преобразуйте формулу в SUM( (2*n)! / (n-1)! ).

Comment: функцию SUM я должен сам составлять?

Comment: SUM просто предполагает заведение переменной-счётчика перед for(){} для накопления в ней результата.

Comment: Нет. Два цикла один за другим. Первый вычислит факториалы от 0 до 2N (в массив), а второй посчитает сумму.

Comment: как вы себе представляете формулу SUM( (2*n)! / (n-1)! )?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю, не стоит мудрить, а просто реализовать шаг за шагом

```
int n;
int sum = 0;
cout << "Введи число: ";
cin >> n;
for (int start = 1; start <= n; start++) {
    int product = 1;
    for (int j = start; j <= 2 * start; j++)
        product *= j;
    sum += product;
}
cout << "Результат: " << sum << endl;
```

P.S. Сейчас увидел прошлую тему автора - так в ней на Паскале точно так же и сделано.

Comment: Интересно, какие аргументы у даунвотеров ;)

Comment: При том, что даже за закрытие вопроса нет ни одного голоса :)

Comment: @MBo,объясните принцип работы вложенного цикла пожалуйста

Comment: @Noob_Prog Начальное число в каждом произведении совпадает с номером (start), а конечное - в два раза больше.

Comment: у нас передаётся значение итератора в первом цикле после иго увеличения на единицу во вложенный?

Comment: Да. Переменная start доступна во всём блоке, относящемся к внешнему for

Answer (score 2):

Я бы действовал так, не начиная считать каждый член суммы заново и не делая второго цикла:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    unsigned int n;
    cin >> n;
    unsigned long long sum = 2, term = 2;    // Первоначальные значения для n == 1
    for(unsigned int i = 2; i <= n; ++i) // Цикл от 2 до n
    {
        term /= i-1;                     // Новый член получается из старого делением на 
        sum += term *= (2*i-1)*2*i;      // первый множитель и умножением на еще два
    }
    cout << sum << endl;
}
```

И еще - для типа результата `int` можно просто сделать табличку из 7 чисел - все равно дальше начинается переполнение :) Впрочем, даже `unsigned long long` тоже хватит только на 14 значений...